# device.uuid not working- phone gap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have the following code for an iPhone phonegap project, it does not showing the device properties,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script src="cordova.2.9.1" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function init(){
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }


            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                // do your thing!
                alert("PhoneGap is working");
                alert(device.cordova);
                alert(device.uuid);
            }

      </script>
    </head>

     <body  onload="onDeviceReady()">

    </body>
</html>
```

here,first alert coming properly while the other alerts not working, my phone gap version is 2.9.0. please help me, i can't go forward .Thanks

Comment: refer- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<body  onload="onDeviceReady()">
```

with:

```
<body  onload="init()">
```

Comment: when i tried this, it is not showing the first alert itself.

Comment: In the init() function you supose to hook the deviceready event. What you are doing is calling directly the deviceready even handler function, and instead it should be called when the event is fired automatically. See in the error console if there is any message, for some reason your cordova library is not firing this event.